# How can I search for a string with a literal backslash when using grep?

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to search `\G` string including the backslash with `grep`.

```
$ echo "\G\\G" > /tmp/test
$ grep '\G' /tmp/test 
\G\G
$ grep '\\G' /tmp/test 
\G\G
$ grep "\\G" /tmp/test 
\G\G
$ grep "\G" /tmp/test 
\G\G
```

Also see the screenshot below for the matches in red:

[image]

I was wondering why only `'\\G'` works?  Is it because of bash only, or because of both bash and grep? Thanks.

Comment: Here's a fun one: `echo '\G' | eval grep \\\\\\\\G`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has to do with what `grep` sees versus what the shell sees.  So, both.

If you want to see what `grep` sees with various forms of quoting, use, for example:

```
printf '<%s>\n' G "G" 'G' \G "\G" '\G' \\G "\\G" '\\G'
```

This will demonstrate what the *shell* does with the various types of quoting.

---

If `grep` sees just a `G`, it will search for (and highlight, with your settings) just the `G` matches.

If `grep` sees a single backslash followed by a `G`, it will (in your implementation and probably all current implementations) consider that the backslash removes any special meaning from the character `G`.  But there isn't any special meaning to `G`, so the result will be the same as if you just pass `G`.

If `grep` sees two backslashes, the first removes the special meaning from the second.  So when `grep` sees `\\G`, it searches for a literal backslash followed by a `G`.  That's what you want.

If you use the `-F` flag to `grep`, to search for a fixed string, you can pass just `\G` and get the same result.  (That is, if you pass `\G` so that `grep` **sees** `\G`, which will require that you escape the backslash in some way so the *shell* doesn't remove it.)

Comment: that `printf` command is very illuminating, it taught me a lot about my shell. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: But why `grep "\\G" /tmp/test ` (with double quotes) didn't work.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro in double quotes, the *shell* interprets backslashes.  So when you type `"\\G"` into the shell, what the *grep* command sees is just `\G` - a single backslash followed by a `G`.  I already covered in my answer what it will do in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In Mentioned example you have mentioned `\G\\G`

`\\G`==> will consisdered as \G only .Back slash will make it treat as normal string instead of special meaning in linux. So first back slash will make next coming string to treat as normal string. So first back slash will be not be consisdered

if You want `\\G` as  normal string then you need to mention as `echo "\G\\\G`"

i tested by using below example

created one file by mentioning below content

cat test.txt

```
\G
\\G
```

If i want to grep only `\G` i will be using below command

```
grep '^\\G' test.txt
```

output

```
\G
```

If i want to grep only `"\\G"` i will be using below command

```
grep '\\\\G' test.txt
```

output

```
\\G
```

Instead of this we can do this by sed command

For find line which contains \G using below command

```
sed -n '/^\\G/p' test.txt
```

For find line which contains `\\G` using below command

```
sed -n '/\\\\G/p' test.txt
```